# Product Conditions

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I was wondering if there is a module that allows to set specific conditions to specific products.

**For example:**

If the qty of product 1 is added or extracted (+1 or -1) other products that are related (not by type: bundle product or virtual product) they should also have there qty changed.

**Condition example:**

if **qty** of **sku1** is -**x** (amount) then change **qty** of **sku2** and **sku3** to -**x**

**Note:** All bold text above should be variables.

I know we should use bundle products or virtual products instead, but since I came to work here all the products were created by simple products.

To change it all back to the correct product type it will take ages because we have almost 100.000k products.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you mentioned as all the product are simple products , how are you saying or in which way is the sku1 , sku2, sku3 are related?

Comment: By creating those conditions mentioned above.